# Unable to bring up the CANbus interface on a Beaglebone black

Tags: network-interface, beagleboneblack, canbus

To automatically bring up the interface on boot, I edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` file as follows:

`debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

And added the following at the end of the file:

```
auto can1
iface can1 inet manual
    pre-up /sbin/ip link set can1 type can bitrate 250000 #triple-sampling on restart-ms 100
    up /sbin/ifconfig can1 up
    down /sbin/ifconfig can1 down
```

But when I reboot, I still need to do `$ sudo /sbin/ip link set can1 up type can bitrate 250000` in order for the `$ candump can1` to work.

What should I do?

[UPDATE] In case it makes a difference, here is my whole `/etc/network/interfaces/``

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

##connman: ethX static config
#connmanctl services
#Using the appropriate ethernet service, tell connman to setup a static IP address for that service:
#sudo connmanctl config <service> --ipv4 manual <ip_addr> <netmask> <gateway> --nameservers <dns_server>

##connman: WiFi
#
#connmanctl
#connmanctl> tether wifi off
#connmanctl> enable wifi
#connmanctl> scan wifi
#connmanctl> services
#connmanctl> agent on
#connmanctl> connect wifi_*_managed_psk
#connmanctl> quit

console


auto can1
iface can1 inet manual
    pre-up /sbin/ip link set can1 type can bitrate 250000
    up /sbin/ifconfig can1 up
    down /sbin/ifconfig can1 down
```

[UPDATE] My `/boot/uEnv.txt`

```
#Docs: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:U-boot_partitioning_layout_2.0

uname_r=4.14.108-ti-r131
#uuid=
#dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb

###U-Boot Overlays###
###Documentation: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#U-Boot_Overlays
###Master Enable
enable_uboot_overlays=1
###
###Overide capes with eeprom
#uboot_overlay_addr0=/lib/firmware/BB-UART1-00A0.dtbo
uboot_overlay_addr1=/lib/firmware/BB-UART2-00A0.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/BB-UART4-RS485-00A0.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr3=/lib/firmware/BB-UART5-00A0.dtbo
###
###Custom Cape
#dtb_overlay=/lib/firmware/<file8>.dtbo
###
###Disable auto loading of virtual capes (emmc/video/wireless/adc)
disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
disable_uboot_overlay_video=1
disable_uboot_overlay_audio=1
disable_uboot_overlay_wireless=1
disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1
###
###PRUSS OPTIONS
###pru_rproc (4.14.x-ti kernel)
uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-14-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_rproc (4.19.x-ti kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_uio (4.14.x-ti, 4.19.x-ti & mainline/bone kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-UIO-00A0.dtbo
###
###Cape Universal Enable
enable_uboot_cape_universal=1
###
###Debug: disable uboot autoload of Cape
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr0=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr1=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr2=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr3=1
###
###U-Boot fdt tweaks... (60000 = 384KB)
#uboot_fdt_buffer=0x60000
###U-Boot Overlays###

cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet

#In the event of edid real failures, uncomment this next line:
#cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e

##enable Generic eMMC Flasher:
##make sure, these tools are installed: dosfstools rsync
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `iface can1 inet auto`

Comment: Sorry `iface can1 inet static` ?

Comment: Nope, same results

Answer (score 1):

Really sorry. By reviewing the entire `etc/network/interfaces`, I noticed there were that weird line:

`console`

just above the `auto can1` line. I believe it's someone's typo into the file.

By removing the line, the interface was brung up as initially expected.

Thanks to everyone